# How to check if element has autoNumeric initialized

Tags: javascript, html, autonumeric.js

How to check if an HTML element already has [autoNumeric](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) initialized, so i won't initialize it again?

Initializing it twice results in all input numbers appearing twice.

```
if (// autonumeric not yet initialized) {
    var anObject = new AutoNumeric(document.querySelector(inputSel), autoNumericSettings);
}
```

Edit: The reason to check is that autoNumeric might be previously initialized elsewhere, in another script with different `autoNumericSettings` and this script needs to respect the earlier set settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

probably, you can use `getAutoNumericElement(domElement)` to check if an HTML element already has autoNumeric initialized

```
if (AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement(domElement) === null) {
    var anObject = new AutoNumeric(document.querySelector(inputSel), autoNumericSettings);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed use `AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement(domElement)` as Aliaksandr mentioned to check if an element is returned, but the *official* way to check if a DOM element is already managed by AutoNumeric is this:

```
AutoNumeric.isManagedByAutoNumeric(domElementOrSelector);
```

So your code should be updated like so:

```
let anObject;
if (!AutoNumeric.isManagedByAutoNumeric(inputSel)) {
    // Also, no need to querySelector `inputSel` here:
    anObject = new AutoNumeric(inputSel, autoNumericSettings);
}
```

*EDIT: Disclaimer; I'm the maintainer of AutoNumeric*

Comment: I inverted this if statement and this solution works well for me.

Comment: My bad, indeed the `if` condition should be negated, I'll edit my answer. Thanks @worktech

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the variable inside the if, do it outside and then just check.

```
var anObject = null;

if(anObject !== null) {
   anObject = new AutoNumeric(document.querySelector(inputSel), autoNumericSettings);
}
```

If you post a bit more of your code I can make it better, I really don't know the structure of your complete code, but the principle is the same.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but doesn't work here. The reason to check is that autoNumeric might be initialized elsewhere, in another script. I edited the question.